# unable to install mongodb properly on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu

Hello i'm getting errors in my terminal everytime i try to apt-get install something or update , i guess it has something to do with installing mongodb , i'm new to linux , i followed this guide exactly on how to install it , i couldnt find a guide for 17.04 version so i did the 16.10 , now everytime i try to apt-get something i get this error

> Reading package lists... Done
>   W: GPG error:
>   http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian wheezy/mongodb-org/3.0
>   Release: The
>   following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is
>   not available: NO_PUBKEY 9ECBEC467F0CEB10 
>   W: The repository
>   'http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian wheezy/mongodb-org/3.0 Release' is
>   not signed.
>   N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and
>   is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
>   N: See apt-secure(8)
>   manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

plus i have an alert in my top bar:

> an error occured please run package manager from the right-click menu
>   or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong

the error message was :

> Error brokenCount > 0. this usually means that your installed packages
>   have unmet dependencies.

Comment: Please ask non-programming questions about Ubuntu at http://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the mongodb repository is not signed. You need to signed using apt-key adv ...

In the URL https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/ there're some ubuntu repositories for mongodb, last available version is 16.04 . Tutorial for setup is also available.

Best luck